# Restore History of Database Snapshots

Tags: sql, sql-server

All,

My business has asked if I can provide a history of the number of times the databases I manage have been reverted to database snapshots.  Does anyone know of a way for me to do this through TSQL?  I've tried a number of approaches with no success.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the information on database backups... you can adjust the WHERE clause to filter for only the database you're interested, and if you GROUP BY and use COUNT in the SELECT list, you can pull just the count of restores... otherwise, this should provide a relatively complete history:

```
SELECT [rs].[destination_database_name], 
       [rs].[restore_date], 
       [bs].[backup_start_date], 
       [bs].[backup_finish_date], 
       [bs].[database_name] as [source_database_name], 
       [bmf].[physical_device_name] as [backup_file_used_for_restore]
  FROM msdb..restorehistory rs
       INNER JOIN msdb..backupset bs ON [rs].[backup_set_id] = [bs].[backup_set_id]
       INNER JOIN msdb..backupmediafamily bmf ON [bs].[media_set_id] = [bmf].[media_set_id] 
 ORDER BY [rs].[restore_date] DESC
```

For database SNAPSHOTS, these are just stored as databases within SQL Server, so you can simply examine the sys.databases view like so:

```
 SELECT * from sys.databases 
 WHERE source_database_id IS NOT NULL
```

As long as you have a decent and consistent naming convention, it should be easy to tell when and where these snapshots were made. As far as I can tell, you can't really know when a revert to snapshot was done without tracking it yourself. But you can tell when the snapshots themselves were made.

Comment: Credit to: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1860/identify-when-a-sql-server-database-was-restored-the-source-and-backup-date/

Comment: That will give me a restore database history, but unfortunately not times that I have reverted to database snapshots.  My guess is that the only way I'll get it is to use an XE to capture the statement and then dump it into a table and query it, but I was wondering if there was an easier way.

Comment: To me "reverting to a database snapshot" means "restoring a previous backed up version of the database"... I guess you mean something different than that.  I snapshot databases by backing them up, and revert them by restoring. So this query gives me all the info I need.

Comment: @pmbAustin: In this case, "snapshot" refers to a database snapshot. As in `create database [foo_snapshot]… as snapshot of [foo]`.

Comment: Updated my answer, but I fear it still doesn't answer your specific wants/needs. If I do figure out an answer that does, I'll update again.